# Deploying python application

Tags: python, iis, deployment, build, packaging

I have created a python application containing rest apis which call machine learning code on PyCharm IDE. I want to deploy rest apis on IIS.

I copy and past complete PyCharm project in virtual directory. The issue I am facing is dependencies like tensorflow and keras are not being found due to which API is giving "Internal server error", however I am able to call rest services.

please guide.

Comment: It maybe better to share what you have *tried*, but if not, why not include those missing/required dependencies within the virtual environment requirements.txt or do a `pip install module-name`.

Answer (score 1):

As [FishingCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5387290/fishingcode) suggested please share code snippet to understand the exact issue.

Please include and install ***requirements.txt*** file in virtual environment.

Also, you may try installing using docker [tutorial](https://blog.sixeyed.com/1-2-3-iis-running-in-nano-server-in-docker-on-windows-server-2016/)